# NDK cannot locate symbol "_Znwj"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've compiled a 3rd party library on Linux using a standalone toolchain, and I'm now trying to load that library in my app.
Problem is I'm getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Znwj" referenced by "libmxnet_predict.so"`

I've tried adding `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, both `APP` & `LOCAL`, but to no avail.

Before you ask, I'm developing with ADT because I have to.

This is my Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

My (simplified) Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARIES)

include  C:/OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE    := FreshubML
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := Mldevlib.cpp \
                    Tablet.cpp \
                    Interface.cpp \

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl -landroid -lm -ljnigraphics -lstdc++
C:\KitchenVision\Workspaces\MLDevWorkspace\MLDev\assets\share
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmxnet_predict
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/armeabi-v7a/libmxnet_predict.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Searching the standalone toolchain I saw that the symbol was referenced in `libgnust_shared.so` which I added to my project via `APP_STL` and in `libstdc++.so` but still, same error.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: FWIW, if you run that symbol through `c++filt`, you get `operator new(unsigned int)`.

Comment: This does not help at all, but thanks all the same.